# What do the colors mean for crafting?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Under the production tab, all my options are now different colors.  They seem to be changing as I use them more.  What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colours are supposed to give you an idea of the amount of crafting experience you'll gain from crafting them, with Gold awarding the most experience, and Grey awarding zero experience.

The formula for crafting experience gained is as follows ([source](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting#Crafting_experience)):

> xp_gain(N) = xp_req(N+1) * multiplier * (1.0 - (N - N_min) / span)

Where:

- **xp_req(x)**: Crafting Experience required for crafting level x.
- **N**: Your crafting level.
- **N_min**: Minimum crafting level required to craft the item.
- **Multiplier**: Determined by the type of item being crafted.

  - **Refinement**: 0.3
  - **Part**: 0.6
  - **Item/Food**: 1.4
- **Span**: Determined by the type of item being crafted. Furthermore, if `N>n_min+span` you will gain *zero* experience from crafting the item.

  - **Refinement**: 25
  - **Part**: 25
  - **Item/Food**: 40

Comment: Okay, so for refinements/parts, if you are 25 crafting levels above the minimum requirement you get no xp, and it's 40 levels for actual item recipes?

Comment: @Gwen Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the amount of experience you will get by crafting them, although I'm not sure of the exact formula (as the amount of XP changes for each item, and is then scaled based on the colour of the recipe) it ranges as follows from "high XP" to "low XP";

- Gold/Orange (lots of XP)
- Yellow
- Green
- Blue
- Teal
- White
- Grey (no XP)

Once a recipe shows as grey, you will no longer get experience. In addition, these recipes can show as Red, which simply means you do not yet meet the requirements to craft that item.