# How does crafting XP relate to actual XP?

Tags: guild-wars-2

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/94753/27134) deals with how much crafting experience you gain from crafting various items but how does the crafting experience translate into actual experience?

I have noticed that levelling up crafting disciplines that you have previously put no effort into (and thus start at crafting level 1) still provides you a noticeable amount of experience even at later levels (50+) so it's obviously not a set amount of experience that you gain from crafting.

Is the quantity of character experience gained directly related to the amount of crafting experience received, is the amount of character experience received exactly the same as crafting experience, or something else entirely?

Comment: XP gain received from crafting is relative to your character's level; going from 1 to 400 in a single crafting discipline will always yield ten levels' worth of XP no matter your current level. Don't have access to the GW2 site and wiki right now so I can't give you URLs to back this up.

Comment: Since there are 80 levels, does that mean levelling up all 8 professions will yield a fully capped character? Obviously it would be reasonably time consuming to get that many materials on hand... or expensive if you used the pay to win store...

Comment: The guy who got the first 80 in the game got his last 10 levels purely from crafting!

Comment: @pixel: Correct. And yes, it'd be either really time consuming or hideously expensive -- but if that's how you want to spend your time playing the game, it's your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of crafting exp to character exp changes depending on your level and your crafting level.

- Craft Level 1-100: each craft level grants 1% of the exp required for character level up.
- Craft Level 101-200: 2%
- Craft Level 201-300: 3%
- Craft Level 301-400: 4%

So, leveling a craft from 1-400 yields enough experience to gain 10 character levels, regardless of your current level. Leveling all crafting disciplines to maximum will take a character to level 80.

Interestingly, the experience gain is weighted toward higher crafting levels, so, for example, leveling all crafts to 100 would only grant 8 character levels, compared to the 10 gained by maxing out a single craft.